# How to use an image other than the app icon in the splash screen for android

Tags: android, dart, icons, flutter

I just added a logo for my app icon in the mipmap folder for android and assets.xcassets folder for IOS and I used a different image for the drawable folder so i can show as the splash screen instead of a pixelated icon logo. however now the app icon is showing the splash screen image and the logo that i designed is not showing. any idea which folder represents the splash screen and which one is for the logo in android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the [flutter launcher icons](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) package, you can change the splash screen as well as the launcher icon of both android and ios.

Comment: I used that package it produced the files needed however the app icon is the same image as the splashscreen which is the problem. here is the code for the icons 
 if it helps: `flutter_icons:
  android: true 
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/App_Icon.png"
  image_path_android: 'assets/icon/App_Icon_Circle.png'
  adaptive_icon_background: "#FFFAFAFA"
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/SplashScreen_Image.png"`

Comment: You can use this this package to create the launcher icon and can probably override it using the splashscreen package if that is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered, but as a suggestion I found a separate splash screen dependency to work well, [available here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/splashscreen)